# An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, composer-php

```
post-install-cmd: @symfony-scripts

symfony-scripts: Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters

Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file

symfony-scripts: Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

[ErrorException] stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception
[RuntimeException] An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

  [ErrorException]                                                               
stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name     
or service not known

Exception trace:
() at /home/docaret/Desktop/AppReact/sparkplant-api-testing/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:293
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at /home/docaret/Desktop/AppReact/sparkplant-api-testing/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:143
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:292
Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:215
Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:81
Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:195
Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:96
Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:323
Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:119
Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:251
Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:59
require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

I got back the work of an app, I retrieved the sources, and I tried to launch API-TEST with composer install but it takes me this error, I try manually with

```
php bin/console cache:clear ==>
 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
[ErrorException] stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

sudo php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod ==>
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPProtocolConnectionException]
ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

I did rm -rf vendor/ var/cache, does not work.

database_host: db
database_port: 3306
database_name: api_platform
database_user: api_platform
database_password: api_platform

rmq.host: rabbitmq
    rmq.port: 5672

i'm intern student trainee... please help me !

Comment: if you are working in a docker container, please run that command in container.

Comment: Try a `rm -rf var/cache/dev`

Comment: thanks but it does not work :(

Comment: with docker-compose up ==> [RuntimeException]  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  ----------------------------stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://rabbitmq:5672 (Connection refused) ----------